# How to deserialize a dictionary containing a list of dictionaries

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, dictionary, deserialization

I am writing a Windows Phone app that will get a set of data from a server and display each entry in a list box.

The data comes from the server looking like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value1": 777103069782066, 
      "value2": "SomeString", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay1"
    }, 
    {
      "value1": 750050696652932, 
      "value2": "SomeString2", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay2"
    }, 
    {
      "value1": 516092242936133, 
      "value2": "SomeString3", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay3"
    } 
  ]
}
```

I know how to get the data into a dictionary like this

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

But it mashes it all into one dictionary entry (to be expected, that's all there is).

How can I take each of the dictionaries contained in the list - contained in the dictionary "data" and be able to store them in a variable(a list, with each list entry being a dictionary of data as shown above)?

Sorry if the question is kind of wordy. I can clarify if needed.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-using-json-net

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but maybe you should change your Dictionary declaration and Deserialization to  *Dictionary< string, Dictionary < string, object>>*.