# How to get elements from json array(or string)?

Tags: asp.net, json

```
{"status":1,"msg":"Success","details":{"123456789":{"id":"4029292","name":"ram"}}}
```

This is my string (I think json array not sure). I got this as response from webservice.

How do I get elements from this?

Comment: I think you need to add more details. Are you using jquery? Are you using ajax?

Comment: How do you plan to consume this web service? c#, javascript?

Comment: WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url");         
 postdata = "jxsdklgjskdgsdkgl..."
 bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
 request.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.Method = "POST";
 Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 dataStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
  dataStream.Close();

 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
 dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 String resp = reader.ReadToEnd(); // reps=response string

Comment: i need to parse the elements in codebehind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to parse it in C#, try using [newtonsoft json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for parsing json response.

> It is simple and easy

Following are some references

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe)

[Link3](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library.
You can use it to deserialize json in both c# and javascript.

```
Message deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json);
```

The Message class would have to map to response you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code to append a json response to the listview.It may be a good example. Also try this (Javascript):

> data.msg[key]
>   or
>    data.msg.123456789.id

```
$.each(data.response, function(key, value) {
            html += '<li><a class=contact href="#" id="' + data.response[key].id + '" ><h1>' + data.response[key].label + '</h1><p>'+ data.response[key].customerName + '</p><p>' + data.response[key].phone + ', ' + data.response[key].email + '</p></a></li>';
            $('#ul_id').append($(html));
            html='';
            console.log('conatct');
            });
```