# How to parse json object in C#?

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

Array:

```
{ 
    "field':["field1":"value1","field2":"value2"], 
            ["field1":"value1","field2":"value2"]
}
```

How to parse the above json response in c#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `json` string you provided is *not correct* in `json` format, the `json` array should be:

```
{"field":[
           {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"},
           {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}
         ]
}
```

You can use [`json.net`](http://json.codeplex.com/) to convert it:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

This tool is also available in nuget.

If you want to use strong type:

```
public class YourObject
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

public class YourClass
{
    public YourObject[] Field { get; set; }
}

var yourClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(json);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [newtonsoft json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) for parsing json response.

> It is simple and easy

I answered same kind of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276255/1196411). *Take a look at it once*

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth taking a look at the javaScriptSerializer Class. and the deserialize method within.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss= new JavaScriptSerializer();
User user = jss.Deserialize<User>(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Coming back to this question some four years later I would definitely recommend using the other answers if you can include this in your project. In my opinion this answer is only really helpful if you can only use .net framework.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of Matt's comment.  

Anytime you can efficiently operate within the framework your project is built on, you should.  Needlessly referencing in out-of-framework libraries can complicate design patterns, mangle conventions, and almost guarantees reliance on scattered documentation.  I'd +1 the answer if it provided more detail.