# Convert an IFile (JSON File) to MyObject

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I upload a JSON file with a HTML form as explained [here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/12/uploading-files-asp-net-core/) in the first paragraph. I accept only 1 file at a time so this is my controller:

```
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
{
}
```

Now I want to convert the file containing JSON to an object. Just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402085/how-to-parse-json-object-in-c) accepted answer of Cuong Le. How do I convert the file to lets say `MyObject`? How do i deserialize the file?
(Newtonsoft is the lib to import right?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the text from the file and then convert to JSON. You can try something like,

```
string fileContent = null;
       using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
       {
         fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(fileContent );
```

Yes, you can use Newtonsoft NuGet package for deserializing.