# javascript object to map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, javascript-objects

I have a list of objects

```
{
  "list": {
    "item": [
      {
        "id": "12",
        "value": "abc"
      },
      {
        "id": "34",
        "value": "pqr"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and want to convert it to a map

```
{"12": "abc", "34","pqr"}
```

What is the easiest way?

I have tried iterating on each object, even Array.map(function), wanna know if there is any easier way

Comment: Is it should be `{"12","abc", "34","pqr"}` or `{"12":"abc", "34":"pqr"}` ? Could you correct that ?

Comment: tried iterating on each object, even Array.map(function). wanna know if there is any easier way

Comment: I noticed you did un-accept my answer, was something wrong? I would like to know what, so I could improve it further, thanks

Comment: sorry, I was trying few actions around the questions and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myObject.list.item.forEach(function(item){
  myMap[item.id] = item.value;
}
```

Something like this would do it...

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop is the easiest way:

```
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < obj.list.item.length; i++) {
    result[obj.list.item[i].id] = obj.list.item[i].value;
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
function map(list, key, value){
    var result = {};
    for(i in list){
        result[list[i][key]] = list[i][value];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then with your object:

```
var list =  {
  "list": {
    "item": [
      {
        "id": "12",
        "value": "abc"
      },
      {
        "id": "34",
        "value": "pqr"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I could call the function like this:

```
map(list["list"]["item"],"id","value")
```

And it will return:
{
    12: "abc",
    34: "pqr"
}

Answer (score 0):

To transform in array or a list with jsondecode in php or in c# with class with deserializate(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net)

Comment: The question is tagged JavaScript. So neither PHP or C# are valid solutions.