# Bind Model to JSON API on other server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and have an existing API which returns JSON. This API exists on another server and I need to make a server-to-server call to API and bind the resultant data to a Model so that it can be used within other parts of this web app I'm making.

I tried searching for this and it seems like it exists but I can't find the basic documentation for it or how to implement it.
I could make each component (make HTTP request, parse the JSON, set a model to use the data), but I'd hate to re-invent the wheel (and probably do it poorly) if this is something that is already in the library.

Example of the API call:

`http://example.info/feeds/feed.aspx?alt=json-in-script`

response:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "feed": {
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-07-08T13:58:21-05:00"
        },
        "id": {
            "$t": "http://example.info/feeds/feed.aspx"
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "Example Calendar of Events"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "rel": "alternate",
                "type": "text/html",
                "href": "http://feed.example.edu/search/"
            },
            {
                "rel": "alternate",
                "type": "application/json",
                "title": "JSON",
                "href": "http://example.info/feeds/feed.aspx?alt=json"
            },
            {
                "rel": "alternate",
                "type": "text/calendar",
                "title": "iCal",
                "href": "http://example.info/feeds/feed.aspx?alt=ical"
            },
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "title": "ATOM Feed",
                "href": "http://example.info/feeds/feed.aspx"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "name": {
                    "$t": "Example!!"
                },
                "email": {
                    "$t": "web@example.edu"
                }
            }
        ],
        "gd$where": [
            {
                "valueString": "Chicago, IL, US"
            }
        ],
        "gCal$timezone": {
            "value": "America/Chicago"
        },
        "entry": [
            {
                "category": [
                    {
                        "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                        "term": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event"
                    },
                    {
                        "term": "Current Students"
                    },
                    {
                        "term": "Faculty"
                    },
                    {
                        "term": "Staff"
                    }
                ],
                "published": {
                    "$t": "2012-03-06T20:57:24+00:00"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2012-03-06T20:57:24+00:00"
                },
                "id": {
                    "$t": "http://example.info/feed/?eventid=74289"
                },
                "gCal$uid": {
                    "value": "e72724e9-34eb-41dd-a75a-78d1577cb98a.127924@feed.example.edu"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": "Last Day of Sessions 1 & 4 Classes"
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "html",
                    "$t": "<p>Session 1 &amp; 4 period ends today.</p>"
                },
                "summary": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": "Session 1 & 4 period ends today."
                },
                "author": [
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "$t": "Office"
                        },
                        "email": {
                            "$t": "registrar@example.edu"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "gd$who": [
                    {
                        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.organizer",
                        "valueString": "Registrar, Office of the"
                    },
                    {
                        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.attendee",
                        "valueString": "Current Students"
                    },
                    {
                        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.attendee",
                        "valueString": "Faculty"
                    },
                    {
                        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.attendee",
                        "valueString": "Staff"
                    }
                ],
                "gd$organization": [
                    {
                        "label": "Campus",
                        "primary": "true",
                        "gd$orgName": {
                            "$t": "Chicago"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "gd": {
                    "value": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.opaque"
                },
                "link": [
                    {
                        "rel": "alternate",
                        "type": "text/html",
                        "href": "http://feed.example.edu/viewevent.aspx?eventid=74289&occurrenceid=127924"
                    }
                ],
                "gCal$sequence": {
                    "value": "0"
                },
                "gd$when": [
                    {
                        "startTime": "2014-07-30",
                        "endTime": "2014-07-31"
                    }
                ],
                "gd$where": [
                    {
                        "valueString": "Classes administered by the Chicago Campus"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

### Edit:

I just now found this article on [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client), which is in-line with what I'm trying to ask with this question, but I need to know how to do this in an ASP.NET MVC context, not a console application.

Comment: Have your action methods in the API controller return `JsonResult`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: ASP.Net Web API 2 could be a good choice if you want to expose API.

Comment: I already have an API established. I want to make use of it in this other web application I'm now building.

Comment: *requesting* the JSON... the API is already in place and I can't touch it.

Comment: Can you show us an example of such a call (including the JSON structure)?

Comment: `I already have an API established.` REST or SOAP?

Comment: @ChrFin I added an example.

Comment: @Win I'm gonna say REST, based on my understanding of it, but we don't do anything with it right now except `GET` requests, and the API is public.

Comment: You have to Enable CORS in your API

Comment: @ScottSelby *sigh* that's not going to be a problem here.

Comment: just a thought when you said you already had working api and want to call it from another client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call an external API you can use the `HttpClient`. Personally, I would wrap the calls to the API in their own class akin to the [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).

```
public class ApiCaller
{    
    /*
      this is the repository that can wrap calls to the API
      if you have many different types of object returned
      from the API it's worth considering making this generic
    */
    HttpClient client;

    public SomeClass Get()
    {
        SomeClass data;

        string url = "http://example.info/feeds/feed.aspx?alt=json-in-script";

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller I would call the ApiCaller to get the object required at which point in this instance I'm just passing it to a view:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ApiCaller caller;

    public MyController()
    {
        //maybe inject this dependency
        ApiCaller = new ApiCaller();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SomeClass model = ApiCaller.Get();

        //do something with the instance if required

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The ApiCaller can then be extended if required to support posts, puts etc. If you have many different entities on the API that you wish to handle you can make an ApiCaller per entity or you could potentially use generics.

Comment: And how would I bind this to a Model? That's the whole point of my question. I know how to make HTTP requests, but it's the ASP.NET part which I'm missing.

Comment: In my example your model would be the class `SomeClass`. I'm using the built in serializer to serialize the response into an object. Is that what you're after or are you looking to auto generate a model class?

Comment: what would the rest of the structure look like? Would this snippet of code that makes the actual request go in the controller? some global class?

Comment: I would typically put it outside in a repository and treat it the same as a database call. You could then make that generic and make `SomeClass` a `T` instead which would obviously make it easier to call different end points that return different results.

Comment: This ended up being closest to what my final solution was, so I'll award the answer. The other part which was kinda glazed over (the building of the JSON/response model) I talk about in this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25063661/940217

Answer (score 0):

You must change from ActionResult to JsonResult. Also you can create a derived class as I did or use native class JsonResult.

```
public JsonResult CheckTimeout()
{
    return Json(new JsonReturn { Success = true, ResponseData = new object() });
}

[Serializable]
public class JsonReturn : JsonResult
{
    public JsonReturn()
    {
        Success = true;
        Message = string.Empty;
        ResponseData = null;
    }

    public JsonReturn(object obj)
    {
        Success = true;
        Message = string.Empty;
        ResponseData = obj;
    }

        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public object ResponseData { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP just stated, that he is on the other side of the request, so this will not help him.