# Parsing unique collection using LINQ to JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON feed using LINQ and can't quite wrap a list of objects/values into a reasonable class.

My JSON looks like:

```
{
   "Project":[
      {
         "ID":"XY1212",
         "Name":"Some Name",
         "Description":"U.S. No 2 Diesel Retail Prices",
         "Manager":"Nora Sims",
         "Dept":"HR",
         "Updated":"2014-07-22",
         "Statistics":[
            [
               "20140722",
               32.22
            ],
            [
               "20140721",
               55
            ],
            [
               "20140720",
               343
            ],
            [
               "20140519",
               43
            ],
            [
               "20140421",
               3.971
            ],
            [
               "20140211",
               40.2
            ],
            [
               "20140210",
               17
            ],
            [
               "20140209",
               16
            ]
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

From the above JSON, I have the following class structure:

```
public class Project
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public string Updated { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> Statistics { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Project> Project { get; set; }
}

public class Statistic
{
    public Datetime ProjectDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal Sale { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to parse the feed and just want the "Statistics" data, but not sure how to get all of the values into the collection of "Statistics":

```
HttpClient() http = new HttpClient();
var json = await http.GetStringAsync(uri);

JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var jList = from values in jo["Project"].Children()["Statistics"]
    select values;
```

When I inspect jList via the following loop:

```
foreach (var stat in jList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stat);
}
```

I can "see" all of the values, but it only loops once, i.e. jList is only one big [0] with a "value" of all of the [x, y], [x1, y1], ..., i.e. looks like an array of one dimension with many 2D arrays inside it.

I want to loop through all of the "arrays", I believe that's what they are, within the [0] I see in Visual Studio while debugging.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error? or just that there is no data parsed?

Comment: I cant remember the exact code, but your Project Class should have a List<Statistics> object in it, and Statistics should be its own class. Kind of like what you have done with RootObject

Comment: Try `var proj = jo["Project"].ToObject<Project>();`. This way you get a `Project` instance which you can easily get `Statistics` from.

Comment: @bit - I have added a Statistic class and the values I am observing while debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you put up the code you are using to loop through?
Should probably be something like..
foreach(Project p in RootObject)
 Foreach(Statistic s in p.Statistics)
   s.projectdate;

Comment: @Seige - I actually did add the foreach loop but had forgotten to wrap around a "code" block. You should be able to view it now better. Thx.

Comment: You are using JSON.Net? Why don't you use the Deserialize that it has? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net

List<Project> Projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(jo);

It may be root projects.

Comment: @AlexKiselev - I tried as you suggested and I got an exception: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Project' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: gotcha. that's not going to work then..

Comment: @Seige - I just updated the above code. I am using JSON.NET with the following: HttpClient() http = new HttpClient();
    var json = await http.GetStringAsync(uri);

Comment: @user118190 I added an answer that should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this easily by making a custom `JsonConverter` for your `Statistic` class.  It will deal with the unconventional JSON and allow you to define your Project class the way you'd really like to have it.

Here is the code for the converter:

```
class StatisticConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Statistic));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        return new Statistic
        {
            ProjectDate = DateTime.ParseExact(array[0].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", 
                            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Sale = array[1].ToObject<decimal>()
        };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, we just need to make a couple of minor changes to your classes.  First, change the `Statistics` property to be a `List<Statistic>` instead of a `List<List<object>>`.  (Don't worry that it doesn't match the JSON-- that's what the converter is for.)

```
public class Project
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public string Updated { get; set; }
    public List<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }
}
```

Next decorate your `Statistic` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to tie it to the custom converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StatisticConverter))]
public class Statistic
{
    public DateTime ProjectDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal Sale { get; set; }
}
```

That's it!  Now you can deserialize as normal, and you'll get a list of statistics the way you want.

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

[Working demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n94gxs).

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your code so much as it is the JSON string that is coming back from the HttpClient.
Because it has parts that don't have a key, it is hard to sort through, also each child of statistic is a child of that child (If my eyes don't deceive me).

However, using the code below, I am able to read the Statistics values singularly

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
            var jList = from values in jo["Project"]
                        select values;
            foreach (var j in jList)
            {
                var l = j["Statistics"].Children();
                foreach (var m in l.Children())
                {
                    string a = m.ToString();
                }
            }
```

On the first loop, m has the Date, On the second loop it has the sale. because there is no key for these, I don't know any other way to reference them.

A bit less code but similar result

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < jo.Count; i++)
        {
            var jList = from values in jo["Project"][i]["Statistics"]
                        select values;                
            foreach (var stat in jList)
            {
                //here stat looks like {["20140722", 32.22]}
            }

        }
```

Comment: Arrgh.... that's what I was assuming all along and was thinking I was going crazy! This JSON feed is horrible. I am looking at your code now, so I should be reporting back soon, thx!