# How to Convert Json string into C# object in MVC4

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a json string which is submitted on controller using Model string value property. I want to convert this json string into c# generic list object.

Below is my json string

```
{
    "MLIDandRackPosition": [
        {
            "MLID": "27",
            "PositionInRack": "3"
        },
        {
            "MLID": "24",
            "PositionInRack": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my class

```
  public class MLIDandRackPosition
    {
        public int MLID { get; set; }
        public int PositionInRack { get; set; }
    }
```

I want a List of MLIDandRackPosition class from json string on controller action method.

Please help

Comment: It's easy to find same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object will bind correctly to

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(IEnumerable<MLIDandRackPosition> MLIDandRackPosition)
```

If you set the following ajax parameters

```
var data = { "MLIDandRackPosition": [ { "MLID": "27", "PositionInRack": "3" }, { "MLID": "24", "PositionInRack": "4" } ] };

$.ajax({
  ...
  traditional: true,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

although I would recommend changing the parameter name (to say `model`) and `var data = { "model": [ { "MLID": ....] };`

Answer (score 4):

With JSON.NET you can do that in a single line:

```
MLIDandRackPosition myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MLIDandRackPosition>(myString);
```

See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm for more about JSON.NET.

Comment: Mr. Dictus very helpful please add 0 after the +1  as i couldn't find the option in SO UI .

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you the [NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library for the .NET platform, is the best when talking of JSON serialization.