# Pass JSON data to action method

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass JSON data from ajax call to my action method -

```
Ajax call - 

$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/ProjectList/getProjects',
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: JSON.stringify(modelData),
         success: function (data) {
                        alert("Testing");
         }
      });
```

Model -

```
EbitModel.cs

public class EbitModel
{
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string SubprojectName { get; set; }
}
```

action method of Controller -

```
ProjectListController.cs


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getProjects(List<EbitModel> modelData)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

But I am getting null here in modelData in this action method.

Is there anything am I missing here?

Edit -

JSON data in ModelData as -

```
[{"ProgramName":"South East","ProjectName":"XYZ","SubprojectName":"LMZ"},{"ProgramName":"South East","ProjectName":"ACB","SubprojectName":"LMZa"}]
```

Comment: what does `modelData` contain?

Comment: @DanielA.White .. it contains JSON data .. E.G. [{"ProgramName":"South East","ProjectName":"XYZ","SubprojectName":"LMN.....]

Comment: Please show modelData,  the problem probably is their. do you have any error in console ?

Comment: try to use var instead of List<EbitModel>...

Comment: public ActionResult getProjects([FromBody] List<EbitModel> modelData){} and change contentType: 'application/json' not contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28360661/1662459

or pass data as string and deserialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some work around for this -

```
var modelData = { "modelData": dt };
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/ProjectList/getProjectsFromEbit',
           dataType: "html",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: JSON.stringify(modelData),
            success: function (data) {

           },
           error: function (data) {

                    }

                });
```

in controller - i took that string and deserialised it

```
public ActionResult getProjectsFromEbit(string modelData)
    {
        var systemOutputList = new List<EbitModel>();
        systemOutputList = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(modelData, systemOutputList);
        return PartialView("_getProjects",systemOutputList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass `modelData` along with Json passing to controller.

Try following code.

```
var jsonString = [{"ProgramName":"South East","ProjectName":"XYZ","SubprojectName":"LMZ"},{"ProgramName":"South East","ProjectName":"ACB","SubprojectName":"LMZa"}];
var jsonData = JSON.parse('{"modelData":'+jsonString +'}')

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ProjectList/getProjects',
    dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: jsonData,
     success: function (data) {
        alert("Testing");
     }
});
```

Comment: Not sure why.. but i am getting internal server error 500 when i use method

Comment: @omkarpatade did you get data in your controller ?

Comment: Nope.. I have place a break point in my action method. But request is going to the action method itself. when i check in console .. its giving internal server error 500

Comment: Do i need to make any changes at controller level (parameter of action method)?

Comment: no all is seems good, need to check something is missing or what

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to hold the model and pass this variable to ajax data

```
var modelHolder = { "Value": @Model.Value }
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/ProjectList/getProjects',
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: modelHolder,
         success: function (data) {
                        alert("Testing");
         }
      });
```