# Importing JSON from ASP.NET server, for JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

**Question**:
What is the best way to pull JSON from a .json file on my server, into code, so it can be deserialized into a .NET object?

**Details**:
I have a file called "backlog.json" saved in my VS2013 Express MVC project. The file was not created by my project - it has been added to the project by doing "Add Existing Item."

"backlog.json" is a collection of json objects. I need to pull these objects from the collection, so I can add to the database my project uses and manipulate with my project.

The project uses .NET Framework 4.5, and I've added [NewtonSoft's Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) to the project, using NuGet package manager. Once I get the objects from "backlog.json" into my code, I'll use Json.NET to deserialize and manipulate the objects through C#.

For example, something like:

```
public void AddJSON(EFWorkOrderModelContainer WorkOrderContainer)
{
    // Pull backlog.json from C:\Project\App_Data\backlog.json
    // De-serialize and parse
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `What is the best way to pull JSON from a .json file on my server` ? Just read it.

Comment: @EZI let me try to clarify... I have a .JSON file saved in my project. I need to use it in code. What's the best way to use a server-side file in code like this?

Comment: Have a look at this post :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net

Comment: Json is just a plain text. Read it from file. Seems like you have some misunderstandings but I don't know what.

Comment: @EZI I guess that's what I'm asking here - what steps are required to read from file?

Comment: @AaronThomas no steps. `string json =  File.ReadAllText(....)`

Comment: @EZI: so, what namespace is required for File.ReadAllText? I'm trying to figure out what to put in my `using` statement...

Comment: @EZI unfortunately this is exactly where I need help. MSDN doc link is broken (ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx). File IO is exactly what this question is about... I'll keep plugging away at it I guess...

Comment: @Noel: post you ref'd is about deserializing - I need to bring in my .JSON file first.

Comment: Are you asking how to load a file ? Is the file part of your solution or is i a standalone file?

Comment: @Noel: yes, that is correct. Trying to load a .JSON file. It is a standalone file that I've added to my project. `string myjson = File.ReadAllText("~\App_Data\backlog.json");` gives an error, says unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: If the file is part of the solution , can you set it as an embedded resource and  load like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: Ahh, actually if I do `string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Project\App_Data\backlog.json");` it seems to work fine. Anyone care to post as an answer, I'll mark as accepted... unless there's a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `string myjson = File.ReadAllText("~/App_Data/backlog.json");`  because `File` class doesn't know how to convert from an application root relative path. You can do `string myjson = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/backlog.json"));` or if `Server` isn't in scope `string myjson = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/backlog.json"));`

You should not do `string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Project\App_Data\backlog.json");` because that's dependent on where you place the website within your web server, and that's a bad idea.

Yes, MSDN is down right now, so you can't use that to look up the namespace for the `File` class. But in Visual Studio, if you just type `File` you can use Intellisense to have it automatically import the namespace for you by right-clicking the `File`.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote so I know what to improve?

Comment: i didn't downvote. Your solution isn't working as expected, but I'm working on narrowing down why.

Comment: looks like I have to include forward slashes or double backslashes with `.MapPath`... but that gets it. Thank you.

Comment: @AaronThomas I fixed the slashes in my answer. You should use forward slashes when it's a URL, or backwards slashes for a Windows based path, and you either have to escape backslashes or use a string literal (`@""`).

Answer (score 0):

I won't mark my own answer as "answered," but a similar way of going about this is actually described on Newtonsoft.com's site. Click [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) to see the sample... it describes exactly what I was looking for.