# new to webservice- how to get number of pages

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I am very new to web services so please provide answer like to a complete beginner.

I am writing an app to consume json webservice data.  But the service may return 15, 20, 200, 500, 1000, ... records.

I need to get them all.

The baseURI could be something like this:

```
http://api.service.com/json/cars/search?&c=suv&l=49.263569,-122.9847682&within=20&units=km
```

I know the service will return something like this:

```
{
  "total_items": "205",
  "page_number": "1",
  "page_size": "10",
  "page_count": "20",
  "cars": {
    "car": [
      { ... },
      { ... },
      ...
      { ... }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, I can see that there is 10 records per page and there is total of 20 pages.  But I know this only once I issue the first request to get the data.

Here is my question:
What is the way to get all 20 pages from a desktop application that shows these records in a a form with a scrollable control.

I thought something like:

```
getResponse(url, 1);  //get first page, this also gives me page_count from response

for (i := 2; i < page_count; i++){
  getResponse(url, i); // loop through number of pages to get each page till the end
}
```

So, above, I pass my url and page_number I want.  First time I want 1st page, then I loop through all pages to get rest of pages by passing next page_number in each request.

Would this be common approach?
How would I do it otherwise if this is not how it should be done?

Note that I don't have some kind of paging system on form, it is just a scrollable view holding all the results.

Comment: I think you can issue the request as the user scrolls down , you don't want to make all those calls if the user doesn't even scroll down , unless it's static and you can just populate it one time

Comment: How do I do that?  Thanks

Comment: Are you just asking how to deserialize JSON in c#?  If so see [Deserializing JSON data to C# using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138) or [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp).

Comment: No, I am asking what is common way to get ALL pages returned by an url?  loneshark99 understood my question.  Thansk,

Comment: @dbnex14 I  know the exact event that fires  when the scroll at touches the end . There has to be some event , when that event fires just hookup your method to fetch the next page and keep a counter of what page is fetched.