# how to read the json object data in c#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the json String

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,
    "responseMessage": "Voucher Code is valid!",
    "responseData": {
        "vouchername": "COMPANY",
        "vouchercode": "sss12",
        "vouchervalue": "100"
    }
}
```

How can i read this JSON data in c# code?

Comment: See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deseralize your json data in different ways.Either make a class for json values or use a dictionary and access data from it after serialization.

For this code You need to add a reference to your project to "System.Web.Extensions.dll"

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(jsonText);
```

You can access your desired fields as

```
bool isSuccess = Convert.ToBool(dict["isSuccess"]);
string vouchername = Convert.ToString(dict["responseData"]["vouchername"]);
```

Comment: For this code You need to add a reference to your project to "System.Web.Extensions.dll"

Answer (score 1):

Use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() to deserialize this string into a Class Type then simply access its properties in the usual way.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public bool isSuccess { get; set; }
    public string responseMessage { get; set; }
    public Responsedata responseData { get; set; }
}

public class Responsedata
{
    public string vouchername { get; set; }
    public string vouchercode { get; set; }
    public string vouchervalue { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access the values like this

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
var strResponseMessage = results.responseMessage ;
var strVoucherName = results.responseData.vouchername;
```

The links provided by dbc are very helpful. Do have a look on it

Comment: Where i can get JsonConvert method?? It is showing error on JsonConvert Method

Answer (score 0):

1. Create c# class that can deserialize your json string. You can do it here json2csharp.com
2. Add newtonsoft json Nuget package to your solution.
3. Then you can deserialize your string like,

> var requestToken =
>   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<(RequestToken)>(Content);

where,
**RequestToken** is your C# class name and **Content** is your json string.

Thanks.