# Handling heterogeneous JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

A project I am working on is consuming Web API's returning heterogeneous JSON, I  don't understand why a webservice API would need to return different object graphs, but that is what is being returned.

My questions are

1. Is it usual/common practice to return different object graphs by the same api? By different object graph I mean a varying complex object that might have or not have some other complex objects as properties. It would have seem reasonable if the same properties returned for every call, either having a null value or a complex object as their values, but the properties being completely omitted in the response makes it hard to have a C# class to desrialise against.
2. How is JSON heterogeneous (de)serialisation handled in C#? Is reflection and run time code generation preferred method for this? or using dynamic/expando object?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense for some APIs to return different objects when some fields that happen to be complex objects are omitted because they do not contain information sometimes, or an endpoint returns different objects based on different parameters. Not sure if there are other cases.

As for different JSON, you have to know a little bit about what data is returned by the API and getting at least the data you need. You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and deserialize to a [class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038318/1685167) or to a [dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972079/1685167) if you are not entirely sure what to expect or don't want to create a class for it.

I also advise to read the API documentation, or do some sort of (boundary?) testing with the parameters to figure out what data to expect.