# Deserialize json data c#

Tags: c#, json, telegram-bot

I want to deserialize JSON response received by [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) by [`getUpdate()`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method.

JSON data:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 920493886,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 123,
        "from": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472457375,
        "text": "Aata aala"
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 920493887,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 124,
        "from": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472457387,
        "text": "Jeva tuzyakadun reply aala tevha"
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 920493888,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 125,
        "from": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472457443,
        "text": "Deposite"
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 920493889,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 127,
        "from": {
          "id": 201520743,
          "first_name": "Chandrakant",
          "last_name": "Kumathekar",
          "username": "chandrakant_k"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 201520743,
          "first_name": "Chandrakant",
          "last_name": "Kumathekar",
          "username": "chandrakant_k",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472457645,
        "text": "\/menu",
        "entities": [
          {
            "type": "bot_command",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 920493890,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 128,
        "from": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472457670,
        "text": "\/menu",
        "entities": [
          {
            "type": "bot_command",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 920493891,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 130,
        "from": {
          "id": 201520743,
          "first_name": "Chandrakant",
          "last_name": "Kumathekar",
          "username": "chandrakant_k"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 201520743,
          "first_name": "Chandrakant",
          "last_name": "Kumathekar",
          "username": "chandrakant_k",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472457848,
        "text": "Deposite"
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 920493892,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 132,
        "from": {
          "id": 201520743,
          "first_name": "Chandrakant",
          "last_name": "Kumathekar",
          "username": "chandrakant_k"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 201520743,
          "first_name": "Chandrakant",
          "last_name": "Kumathekar",
          "username": "chandrakant_k",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472457883,
        "text": "Deposite"
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 920493893,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 133,
        "from": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472468407,
        "text": "\/menu",
        "entities": [
          {
            "type": "bot_command",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 920493894,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 134,
        "from": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 219633031,
          "first_name": "Shreeeeeee",
          "username": "Winner7777",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1472473070,
        "text": "\/menu",
        "entities": [
          {
            "type": "bot_command",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have generated classes from json2csharp

```
public class From
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}

public class Chat
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public Chat chat { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> entities { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int update_id { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool ok { get; set; }
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

using newtonsoft to deserialization

```
var d = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rcvd_data);
```

what to do next? how to put this all at work? I am confused please help.

Comment: Specify a type when you use DeserializeObject, like so: `Message message = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(rcvd_data);`. And then you can retrieve the Message properties (`message.text`).

Comment: this question was asked ~500 times and shows no research effort!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON data to C# using JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deserialization use this code:

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rcvd_data);
```

And in `ro` you have all data.

**EXAMPLE**

```
bool ok = ro.ok;

foreach(Result r in ro.result)
{
    int uId = r.update_id;
    Message m = r.message;
    int msgId = m.message_id;
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply i did as you said everything goes okk but i get some values null as i compile it. is i missing something??

Comment: What values have you null? I check it

Comment: Result Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(rcvd_data);
    int id = Result.update_id;

Comment: Message message = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(rcvd_data);
            string msgid = message.message_id.ToString();
            string msgtxt = message.text;

            Chat cht = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Chat>(rcvd_data);
            int cht_id = cht.id;
            string frst_nm = cht.first_name;

Comment: also this object i am getting null values

Comment: @ckjon dont deserialize to `Result`, deserialize to `RootObject`. Then in ro you get list of Result.

Comment: @yes, i udpated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much @BWA it was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
string data = @"{""ok"":true,""result"":[{""update_id"":920493886,...";

RootObject ro = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);

foreach (Result result in ro.result)
{
        //two example fields
        Console.WriteLine("update_id= " + result.update_id);
        Console.WriteLine("message text= "+result.message.text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on: https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json (Source: https://yts.am/api)

I used: http://json2csharp.com/ to create classes
[Copy and paste the result of the get request of postman to json2csharp to automatically create the classes that you need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keBEY.png)

And once created, i used them on a Service like this:

```
 private string URL = "https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json";
    public async Task<List<Movie>> GetMovies()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(URL);
        RootObject lista = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        List<Movie> todoes = lista.data.movies;
        return todoes;
    }
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var d = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rcvd_‌​data);
```

then `d` will contain list of `RootObject`. By iterating using `foreach` you can get all the properties of `RootObject` model

Comment: Judging by the Json data, it should be deserialized to the `RootObject` class instead. From that object, you can access a list of `Message` objects.

Comment: yes first time I do mistake but unfortunately during edit my power was gone so can't edit, now ok