# Get value from a Json string

Tags: c#, json

I have a Json sting like

```
var Result= [{"CompanyID":32,"Roles":["Admin"]}]
```

I need to get the value of CompanyID from this.

I tried something like

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(Result);
int Id=obj["CompanyID"];
```

but it throwing some error "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."

can anyone help

thanks in advance for help .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON data to C# using JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual problem is that you are trying to parse this to `JObject` when you actually have an array of objects. You can first parse it to an array, then index the array to select the only object, and select your `CompanyID` key then grab the value as an `int`

```
var Result = "[{\"CompanyID\":32,\"Roles\":[\"Admin\"]}]";
// Parse your Result to an Array
var jArray = JArray.Parse(Result);
// Index the Array and select your CompanyID
var obj = jArray[0]["CompanyID"].Value<int>();
```

Alternatively, you can also map the JSON to a concrete type if it's a structure you will work with often. This is more beneficial as you will have compile time checking - in the event of making a spelling mistake or capitalization error when selecting one of the keys.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Result = "[{\"CompanyID\":32,\"Roles\":[\"Admin\"]}]";
        var cList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Company>>(Result);

        var obj = cList.First().CompanyID;
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```