# converting JSON string to C# Object

Tags: c#, json

I tried to deserialize JSON string to object, but got an exception, really confused.

```
"{

\"lastUpdateId\":787618462,
\"bids\":[[\"10451.90000000\",\"0.18884000\"],[\"10451.70000000\",\"0.01770200\"]],

\"asks\":[[\"10457.88000000\",\"0.17060500\"],[\"10458.13000000\",\"0.79300000\"]]

}"
```

and this is the needed object:

```
 public class OrderBook
    {
        [JsonProperty("lastUpdateId")]
        public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("asks")]
        public List<OrderBookOrder> Asks { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("bids")]
        public List<OrderBookOrder> Bids { get; set; }

        public OrderBook(List<OrderBookOrder> asks, List<OrderBookOrder> bids)
        {
            Asks = asks;
            Bids = bids;
        }
        public OrderBook()
        {

        }
    }

    public class OrderBookOrder
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }

        public OrderBookOrder(decimal price, decimal volume)
        {
            Price = price;
            Volume = volume;
        }
    }
```

so then I use NewtonSoft Json to convert the string to object

```
 public static implicit operator OrderBook(ApiResponse response)
        {
            return Utilities.ConverFromJason<OrderBook>(response);
        }
```

I think that problem is to parce two arrays (bids and asks) but can`t solve the problem. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Can you share what is the error?

Comment: _"an exception"_. That's broad.

Comment: What is the result if you convert the object to json? So you can compare the difference.

Comment: just returns a null object from Utilities class

Comment: i use this function called from Utilities class                                                 
     public static T ConverFromJason<T>(ApiResponse response) where T : class, new()
        {
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Log.LogMessage("Empty JSON Object!");
                return new T();
            }
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON data to C# using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net)

Answer (score 3):

The JSON you gave must have class structure as shown

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> bids { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> asks { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use Newtonsoft.Json (from nuget). All you have to do is:

```
OrderBook ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderBook>(response.ToString());
```

Your model must be something like this:

```
public class OrderBook
{
    [JsonProperty("lastUpdateId")]
    public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("bids")]
    public List<List<string>> bids { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("asks")]
    public List<List<string>> asks { get; set; }
}
```

You can get a proper model from json string here: http://json2csharp.com/

Important! All your Json properties must have public getter and setter. Even if you only serialize or deserialize.

To fill your OrderBookOrder object, you have to create one specific method and call it after deserialize. It is not possible to transform a JSon model into something different using Newtonsoft.Json.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question your model class looks like below

```
public class OrderBook
{

    [JsonProperty("lastUpdateId")]
    public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bids")]
    public IList<IList<string>> Bids { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("asks")]
    public IList<IList<string>> Asks { get; set; }
}
```

And valid json format look like below

```
{
"lastUpdateId": 787618462,
"bids": [
    [".90000000 ", "0.18884000 "],
    ["10451.70000000 ", "0.01770200 "]
],
"asks": [
    ["10457.88000000", "0.17060500"],
    ["10458.13000000", "0.79300000"]
]
}
```

You can write for DeserializeObject code

```
public static implicit operator OrderBook(ApiResponse response)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderBook>(response);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Fluent-JSON.NET if you do not want to pollute your models with attributes.