# Deserialize dynamic json into generic .NET object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

What is the best way to deserialize the following JSON response into a generic object? For example I would like to access the response message and a the list of errors (and accessing the field name and error message of it).

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
      "name": [
          "Name is required."
      ],
      "gender": [
          "Gender is required."
      ],
      "date_of_birth": [
          "Date of birth is required."
      ]
  }
}
```

Edit:

I would like to access the JSON object in a way something like this

```
string message = genericObject.message
foreach (error errorElement in genericObject.errors)
{
  string errorField = errorElement.fieldName;
  string errorDescription = errorElement.errorMessage;
}
```

Edit 2:

I don't know the possible error fields beforehand.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by a "generic object"? If you mean something with `<T>`, can't you simply tell us which objects are involved? If you mean something like `dynamic`, please say so.

Comment: I would create a proper class for that json, something like `public class Response { public string Message { get; set; } public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Errors { get; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); }`

Comment: I made some edits to clarify my question.

Comment: Words like "generic" and "dynamic" can confuse because they have very specific meaning. In this case you wouldn't need to create anything complex or generic or use `dynamic`. I think what you want is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net. Ignore the part of the question that sounds different from yours and look at the answers.

Comment: Did you try the class I provided in my comment above? You can deserialize into it with something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention that you do not know which "error fields" will be present, a dictionary is the best way to go.

Here's a simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\temp\test.json");
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
    response.Dump();
}

public class Response
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Errors { get; }
        = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
}
```

When executing this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net), I get this output:

[image: sample LINQPad output]

You can even add your own code from your question:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\temp\test.json");
var genericObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);

string message = genericObject.Message;
foreach (var errorElement in genericObject.Errors) // see note about var below
{
  string errorField = errorElement.Key;
  string errorDescription = errorElement.Value.FirstOrDefault(); // see below
}
```

**Note 1:** The result of iterating a dictionary is a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, in this case it would be a `KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>`.

**Note 2:** You've shown JSON having an array for each field, so `errorElement.errorMessage` isn't going to work properly since you may have multiple error messages.

You can nest some loops, however, to process them all:

```
string message = genericObject.Message;
foreach (var errorElement in genericObject.Errors) // see note about var below
{
  string errorField = errorElement.Key;
  foreach (string errorDescription in errorElement.Value)
  {
    // process errorField + errorDescription here
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a very similar issue, where the object is slightly different and I can't find the structure to use to deserialize:  Metadata: [{propA: "81", propB: 50}]   As you can see the values could also be different, not all strings. Field names are not known, as well as the number of them

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.

The `System.Web.Helpers` assembly contains the `Json` class which you can do:

```
dynamic decodedObject = Json.Decode(json);
```

Another way would be to use the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nuget package:

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) you can use:

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(originalJson);
```

Answer (score 1):

you would have to create the following classes:
`RootObject.cs` containing the following properties:

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public Errors Errors { get; set; }
}
```

`Errors.cs`, containing the following properties:

```cs
public class Errors
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string[] Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gender")]
    public string[] Gender { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date_of_birth")]
    public string[] DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

And then you read the whole thing like this:

```cs
var inputObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Where `inputObj` will be of type `RootObject` and `json` is the JSON you are receiving.

If you have implemented this correctly, use it like this:

```cs
var message = inputObj.Message;
var nameErrors = inputObj.Errors;
var firstNameError = inputObj.Errors.Name[0];
```

Here is a visual:
Showing the whole object, filled with the properties:
[image]

The "main" error:
[image]

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I don't know which error fields I can expect beforehand.

Comment: If that just means that `fieldName` might contain different values, I wouldn't use `dynamic`. I'd steer far away from that unless there's a very specific reason why you need it. If the data you're receiving is in a predictable structure and it's only the values that are changing (which is most of the time) then you can just define a class (or generate one using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and deserialize that.