# How to return object with dynamic fields

Tags: c#, object, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create a line graph for each store in every month of the year. However, store is dynamic it depends on the merchant. This is the return query from the db:

```
[{"Month":"January","Total":44,"Store":"Refoil"},
{"Month":"January","Total":242,"Store":"Sustainable Salons"},
{"Month":"January","Total":99,"Store":"The Base Collective"},
{"Month":"February","Total":37,"Store":"Refoil"},
{"Month":"February","Total":219,"Store":"Sustainable Salons"},
{"Month":"February","Total":122,"Store":"The Base Collective"},
{"Month":"February","Total":148,"Store":"Watersco Australia"}]
```

How can I return an object this like:

```
[{"Month":"January","Refoil":44,"Sustainable Salons":242},

{"Month":"February","Refoil":2,"Sustainable Salons":10}]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Group by name of store and month? You could use LINQ for such things.

Comment: Do you want to return a JSON string?

Comment: I need to achieve like this: {"Month":"January","Refoil":44,"Sustainable Salons",242}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ExpandoObject` to transpose the results:-

```
var results = new List<Result>();

results.Add(new Result() { Month = "January", Total = 44, Store = "Refoil" });
results.Add(new Result() { Month = "January", Total = 242, Store = "Sustainable Salons" });
results.Add(new Result() { Month = "January", Total = 99, Store = "The Base Collective" });
results.Add(new Result() { Month = "February", Total = 37, Store = "Refoil" });
results.Add(new Result() { Month = "February", Total = 219, Store = "Sustainable Salons" });
results.Add(new Result() { Month = "February", Total = 122, Store = "The Base Collective" });
results.Add(new Result() { Month = "February", Total = 148, Store = "Watersco Australia" });

var transpose = results.GroupBy(x => x.Month).Select(x =>
{
    dynamic e = new ExpandoObject();

    e.Month = x.Key;

    var ed = e as IDictionary<string, object>;

    x.ToList().ForEach(y => ed.Add(y.Store, y.Total));

    return e;
});

Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transpose, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

`Result` class:-

```
public class Result
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Store { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

Gives the following output:-

```
[
  {
    "Month": "January",
    "Refoil": 44,
    "Sustainable Salons": 242,
    "The Base Collective": 99
  },
  {
    "Month": "February",
    "Refoil": 37,
    "Sustainable Salons": 219,
    "The Base Collective": 122,
    "Watersco Australia": 148
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I find it hard to display in line graph in moris.js.

Comment: How can I set to 0 in total if that store not exist in that month?

Comment: @Jen143, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57423156/1196867) which discusses how to use an outer join to include missing values. You could apply that to your `results` list before you use the dynamic code above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Deserialize your json to c# object refer
   [Deserializing JSON data to C# using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net)
2. Group by month using linq and json serialize your c# object and send it to your client side..

If this doesn't help, please provide more details, what would you expect after group by your data by month?.

Answer (score 0):

Map db response into c# model, and than create anonymous object with needed structure and serialize with Json.Net.
If this not result you want, please add more details