# Unsure how to properly extract data into a list of a class that contains a string, int and double property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with asp.net MVC, trying to make a table that shows a brands total profits each day, over a number of days, and I'm struggling with how to include days where a brands net profit is 0.

After I query the store's total number of purchases in the given time frame, in a var called purchaseQuery, which gives me the brand's name, the day of purchase (as an int), the price of that item, and the amount of said item purchased in that transaction. Assume each brand only sells one product, and the product's price fluctuates each day.
This code is after that query.

```cs
purchasedItems = new List<BrandsTransactionItem>();

foreach (var query in purchaseQuery)
{
BrandsTransactionItem tempItem;
tempItem = purchasedItems.Where(e => e.day == query.day).Where(e => e.brandName == query.brandName).FirstOrDefault();

//If item not in list already, 
if (tempItem == null)
{
   purchasedItems.Add(new BrandsTransactionItem()
   {
    brandName = query.brandName,
    day = query.day,
    totalPurchased = query.TotalPurchased,
    costOfItem = query.costOfItem
   });
}
// if it already exists, just add to amount purchased
else
{
  tempItem.totalPurchased += query.totalPurchased;
}
}

foreach (var item in purchasedItems)
{
  double dailyProfit = (double)(item.totalPurchased * item.costOfItem);
  dailyProfit = Math.Round(dailyProfit, 2); // make it decimal of 2

  // Items is the list that I want to display in MVC
  Items.Add(new BrandsProfit(){
  brandName = item.brandName,
  day = item.day,
  totalDailyProfit = dailyProfit
  });
}
```

I want to transition so BrandsProfit will have a name, a list of days, and a list of dailyProfits corresponding to each of those days. That way each item in the Items list will have a unique brand name, as it will apply to every purchase made, rather than an item only for days where a brand's item was purchased.

I feel like I'm over complicating things with this, my main worry is that if a brand has 0 purchases for a day, I could have a list of days of a size of 5, and a list of purchases that has a size of 4, and I need their sizes to be the same.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of problem is a great candidate for using LINQ.

The LINQ query below first creates an outer join of distinct days and brand names. This gives us a list of all brands for all days that we can join against. That way each brand will have the same number of days, even if it never sold any items on a particular day.

It then joins the purchases against that list of brands/days, and if there were no purchases recorded for that brand on that day it creates a stand-in purchase with zero cost/quantity using `DefaultIfEmpty`.

The result of that join is then projected into a list of `BrandsProfit` objects.

For an example of what happens if there is no purchase for a brand on a particular day, you'll notice in the list of sample data that brand "B" on day "2" is commented out; yet in the results there is still a row for brand "B" on day "2", with a TotalDailyProfit of zero.

```
void Main()
{
    var purchases = new List<Purchase>() {
        new Purchase() { BrandName = "A", CostOfItem = 1.13M, Day = 1, TotalPurchased = 125 },
        new Purchase() { BrandName = "B", CostOfItem = 1.52M, Day = 1, TotalPurchased = 165 },
        new Purchase() { BrandName = "C", CostOfItem = 1.90M, Day = 1, TotalPurchased = 836 },
        new Purchase() { BrandName = "A", CostOfItem = 1.74M, Day = 2, TotalPurchased = 583 },
        //new Purchase() { BrandName = "B", CostOfItem = 1.52M, Day = 2, TotalPurchased = 785 },
        new Purchase() { BrandName = "C", CostOfItem = 1.42M, Day = 2, TotalPurchased = 369 },
        new Purchase() { BrandName = "A", CostOfItem = 1.93M, Day = 3, TotalPurchased = 789 },
        new Purchase() { BrandName = "B", CostOfItem = 1.87M, Day = 3, TotalPurchased = 739 },
        new Purchase() { BrandName = "C", CostOfItem = 1.78M, Day = 3, TotalPurchased = 436 },
    };

    var results = from day in purchases.Select(x => x.Day).Distinct()
                  from brand in purchases.Select(x => x.BrandName).Distinct()
                  join purchase in purchases on new { Brand = brand, Day = day } equals new { Brand = purchase.BrandName, Day = purchase.Day } into j
                  from result in j.DefaultIfEmpty(new Purchase() { BrandName = brand, Day = day, TotalPurchased = 0, CostOfItem = 0 })
                  select new BrandsProfit()
                  {
                      BrandName = result.BrandName,
                      Day = result.Day,
                      TotalDailyProfit = result.TotalPurchased * result.CostOfItem
                  };

    Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
}

class Purchase
{
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int TotalPurchased { get; set; }
    public decimal CostOfItem { get; set; }
}

class BrandsProfit
{
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDailyProfit { get; set; }
}
```

Produces the following result:-

```
[
  {
    "BrandName": "A",
    "Day": 1,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 141.25
  },
  {
    "BrandName": "B",
    "Day": 1,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 250.80
  },
  {
    "BrandName": "C",
    "Day": 1,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 1588.40
  },
  {
    "BrandName": "A",
    "Day": 2,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 1014.42
  },
  {
    "BrandName": "B",
    "Day": 2,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 0.0
  },
  {
    "BrandName": "C",
    "Day": 2,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 523.98
  },
  {
    "BrandName": "A",
    "Day": 3,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 1522.77
  },
  {
    "BrandName": "B",
    "Day": 3,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 1381.93
  },
  {
    "BrandName": "C",
    "Day": 3,
    "TotalDailyProfit": 776.08
  }
]
```

If you didn't want to go down the road of using the example above, you could consider updating the source query you use to generate the data in your `purchaseQuery` to use an outer join like the one above... that way you would have a row for every combination of brand/day, even if a brand never sold on a particular day.